# How to solve "Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported" without adding the ICU libraries on the docker container?

Tags: c#, docker-compose, .net-7.0, globalization

We are working on a .NET microservices project for a client which will deploy it on Linux docker containers.

After using the client's sdk-alpine as a base image for docker containers we encountered this problem when trying to connect to SQL server:

> "Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported"

we are using:
.NET 7 and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version 7.0.13

I have searched and found that alpine does not contain ICU libraries so I added them and it worked, However we can't add new libraries (for some reason unknown to me). So now I'm trying to find another solution if it exists before jumping and telling them there is no other way.
Is there a way to enable global invariant or

I tried enabling NLS instead of ICU in docker-compose 'DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_USENLS=true' however still not working

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you with this error.
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/220

Comment: Yes, i saw this post, however i want to know if there a solution to enable globalization invariant mode or enabled it without adding ICU libraries to sdk-alpine docker image

Comment: Removing the following from the Project file resolves the error:

<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>